# Magento2 changes

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

Hi I am new in `Magento 2` and I want to know where I have to put the
 `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` file, I tried to copy the file and put it in `c:\wamp\www\kk2\app\design\frontend\Magento\MyStore\layout`
folder and is not working. I also tried in `c:\wamp\www\kk2\app\design\frontend\Magento\MyStore\module-theme\layout` and other options but I can't figure where I have to put this to start modifying the theme, the documentation on the Magento offical page is not very clear.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "is not working"? Are there any error messages? What behavior is happening vs what you expect?

Comment: Hi , i want to start modifying a theme that i have installed and i don't want it to do it in this directory vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml      i want to do it in my theme directory c:\wamp\www\kk2\app\design\frontend\Magento\MyStore\ like in Magento 1 you can do this just copying the file in your template folder but i don't know the right way to do it in Magento 2

Comment: or there is another way to start theming Magento 2 ??

Comment: Can you please tell us how you deployed? via zip from magento.com or git clone or composer create project? Also, are you attempting to create your own theme?

Comment: via zip from magento.com, i created a theme that inherit from luma's theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create folder and copy `default.xml` file in your theme

`app/design/frontend/magento/<your_theme_name>/magento_theme/layout/default.xml`

remove generate folder and run

`sudo php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

It's working

Comment: Thank you Suman, you are the only one who could answer me correctly, you are the best

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to copy any file. You can create your own theme. 
 Quoting steps in [create a theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html)

> 1. Create a directory for the theme under `app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>`.
> 2. Add a declaration file `theme.xml` and optionally create `etc` directory and create a file named `view.xml` to the theme directory.
> 3. Add a `composer.json` file.
> 4. Add `registration.php`.
> 5. Create directories for CSS, JavaScript, images, and fonts. Configure your theme in the Admin
>      panel.

The Luma theme is **not** designed to be inherited from. Please see [this comment on Github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2547#issuecomment-160783766). You can however, inherit from the blank theme as follows:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
 <title>New theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
 <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
 <media>
     <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
 </media>
```

Comment: ok, my question was not how to create a theme beacuse i already did that, my question is how i need to start to modify my theme, where i have to put the files i want to modify?,  for example if i want to modify this vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml    i don't want to modify in that directory beacuse that will cause troubles in future updates, i want to know where i have to put this file in my theme to start modifying ???

Comment: @vlad666 it's all in the documentation - follow Maddy's link and have a read of it

Comment: You will have to extend from that theme, and then remove an element in your theme, and replace it with a new one. Example here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_remove_elements

Comment: even if i inherit from the blank theme i still don't know where i have to put the file vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml in my theme to start editing it, the documentation about this is not clear to me